# TO change a single row filed to 1 and all other to zero codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

can any one please provide the codeigniter equivalent of this above code

`UPDATE table SET 'status_field'=IF(id=4, 1, 0)`

the code will toggle all values of `status_field` to `0` and for the the specified row (with `id=4`) sets the `status_field` to `1`

Comment: What's your codeigniter version? In any case, you should take a look at the query function that let you run SQL script freely.

Comment: for CI 3.0 follow this: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=set#CI_DB_query_builder::set for SET and this https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=set#CI_DB_query_builder::update for UPDATE

Comment: You might want to add the codeigniter version you're working with to the question tags.